# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null when moving out from a specific page

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app I have a `search` page which is a complex page with many nested controller.

Only in that page, when I move out to any other page, I receive the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

And the next page is blank. The navbar remains, so if I move to another page, everything continue normally.

This is the router:

```
this.resource('products', function(){
  this.route('search');
});
```

This is `routes/products/search.js`:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {});
```

The template contains 3 nested `#each`, any of them with a specific `itemController`:

```
{{#each subset in subsets itemController="products/search/subset"}}
  {{#each panel in subset.panels itemController="products/search/panel"}}
    {{#each value in panel.values itemController="products/search/value"}}
```

Every array is an array of `Ember.Objects`, like:

```
var Subset = Ember.Object.extend({
  panels: []
});
// 
var Panel = Ember.Object.extend({
  values: []
});
```

I think that some callback is called when I change page and something during the cleaning of the controllers causes the error, but I really don't know how to find the error. I tried to debug using the console, but the error comes from vendor.js and nothing pointed me to a line in my files.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of debugging and different attempts, I found that the error was due to the wrong type of controller I used.

I defined the controllers as `Ember.ArrayController.extend({});`.

Changing to `Ember.ObjectController.extend({});` resolved the error